# how to add onClickListener instead of replacing listener?

Tags: java, android, view, listener, onclicklistener

I try to add on click listener to my android view.

however, when I add with this code:

```
public interface SwipeableButtonListener {
    public void onClick();
    public void onSwipe();
}

private SwipeableButtonListener listener = null;


public void setOnClickListener(SwipeableButtonListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

the current listener is replaced and not a new one is added to the registered one.

how can I change this? creating listener ArrayList is the only way?

does native addOnClickListener override existing listener or adds to a built-in listener list?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: add a new listener to an existing one.

Comment: Why would you want more than 1 `OnClickListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern that I use is along these lines:

```
private List<SwipeableButtonListener> listeners;

public void addOnClickListener(SwipeableButtonListener listener)
{
    if(listeners == null)
        listeners = new ArrayList<SwipeableButtonListener>();

listeners.add(listener);
}

private void fireButtonSwipedListeners()
{
    if(listeners != null){
     for(SwipeableButtonListener listener: listeners){
           listener.onSwipe();}
    }
}
```

Comment: does native addOnClickListener override existing listener or adds to a built-in listener list?

Comment: well standard buttons have setOnClickListener, which replaces the previous one I believe. Some objects use the convention add..Listener in which case they are added and not replaced

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public interface SwipeableButtonListener {
    public void onClick();
    public void onSwipe();
}

private final List<SwipeableButtonListener> swipeableButtonListeners = new ArrayList<SwipeableButtonListener>();


public void addOnClickListener(SwipeableButtonListener listener) {
    this.swipeableButtonListeners.add(listener);
}
```

Comment: does native addOnClickListener override existing listener or adds to a built-in listener list?

Comment: It adds to a built-in list. If it would override existing listeners the method would be called setOnClickListener().

Comment: my bad, there is only native setOnClickListener(). so there is no way to add few listeners natively?

Comment: No, natively there is not way to attach multiple listeners, but there is nothing preventing you from adding one listener, and doing multiple  things in its callback.